# Complex mysql selection query

Tags: mysql, sql, django

my table is like this:

```
------------------------------------
id | value    |  date_value
------------------------------------
1  |    a     |  2013-01-01T00:00:00
2  |    a     |  2013-01-01T05:00:00
3  |    b     |  2013-01-01T03:00:00
4  |    a     |  2013-01-02T00:00:00
5  |    a     |  2013-01-03T00:00:00
6  |    c     |  2013-01-06T00:00:00
7  |    a     |  2013-01-10T05:00:00
8  |    a     |  2013-01-10T06:00:00
9  |    a     |  2013-01-10T07:00:00
```

I'd like to select `((more than 2 times duplicate`value`'s count) /(`value`'s count except duplicate))`

In the above case, result is 1/3 (because only value `a` is 2 times more than duplicate).

How do i make sql for do that?

Comment: you might want to look into the django annotations (aggregations on count is what you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what `more than 2 times duplicate value's count` means.
if this means a value that appears more than 4 times, you shoud:

```
select value
from your_table
group by value
having count(*) >= 4
```

Four can be replaced with desired value. May it's two, I'm not sure.

The second part seems to be:

```
select count(distinct value) from your_table;
```

So a final sql, considering first part ask just for duplicates, may look like:

```
select count(value) / (select count(distinct value) from your_table)
from(
    select value
    from your_table
    group by value
    having count(*) >= 2
    )
```